# Linux router: ping doesn't route back

Tags: debian, router, local-area-network, ping

I have a Debian box which I'm trying to set up as a router and an Ubuntu box which I'm using as a client.

**My problem is that when the Ubuntu client tries to ping a server on the Internet, all the packets are lost** (though, as you can see below, they seem to go to the server and back without problem).

I'm doing this in the Ubuntu Box:

```
# ping -I eth1 my.remote-server.com
PING my.remote-server.com (X.X.X.X) from 10.1.1.12 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- my.remote-server.com ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 12094ms
```

(I changed the name and IP of the remote server for privacy).

From the Debian Router I see this:

```
# tcpdump -i eth1 -qtln icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
IP X.X.X.X > 10.1.1.12: ICMP echo reply, id 305, seq 7, length 64
IP 10.1.1.12 > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 305, seq 8, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > 10.1.1.12: ICMP echo reply, id 305, seq 8, length 64
IP 10.1.1.12 > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 305, seq 9, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > 10.1.1.12: ICMP echo reply, id 305, seq 9, length 64
IP 10.1.1.12 > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 305, seq 10, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > 10.1.1.12: ICMP echo reply, id 305, seq 10, length 64
IP 10.1.1.12 > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 305, seq 11, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > 10.1.1.12: ICMP echo reply, id 305, seq 11, length 64
^C
9 packets captured
9 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel

# tcpdump -i eth2 -qtln icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
IP 192.168.1.10 > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 360, seq 213, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > 192.168.1.10: ICMP echo reply, id 360, seq 213, length 64
IP 192.168.1.10 > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 360, seq 214, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > 192.168.1.10: ICMP echo reply, id 360, seq 214, length 64
IP 192.168.1.10 > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 360, seq 215, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > 192.168.1.10: ICMP echo reply, id 360, seq 215, length 64
IP 192.168.1.10 > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 360, seq 216, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > 192.168.1.10: ICMP echo reply, id 360, seq 216, length 64
IP 192.168.1.10 > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 360, seq 217, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > 192.168.1.10: ICMP echo reply, id 360, seq 217, length 64
^C
10 packets captured
10 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

And at the remote server I see this:

```
# tcpdump -i eth0 -qtln icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
IP Y.Y.Y.Y > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 360, seq 1, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > Y.Y.Y.Y: ICMP echo reply, id 360, seq 1, length 64
IP Y.Y.Y.Y > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 360, seq 2, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > Y.Y.Y.Y: ICMP echo reply, id 360, seq 2, length 64
IP Y.Y.Y.Y > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 360, seq 3, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > Y.Y.Y.Y: ICMP echo reply, id 360, seq 3, length 64
IP Y.Y.Y.Y > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 360, seq 4, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > Y.Y.Y.Y: ICMP echo reply, id 360, seq 4, length 64
IP Y.Y.Y.Y > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 360, seq 5, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > Y.Y.Y.Y: ICMP echo reply, id 360, seq 5, length 64
IP Y.Y.Y.Y > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 360, seq 6, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > Y.Y.Y.Y: ICMP echo reply, id 360, seq 6, length 64
IP Y.Y.Y.Y > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 360, seq 7, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > Y.Y.Y.Y: ICMP echo reply, id 360, seq 7, length 64
IP Y.Y.Y.Y > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 360, seq 8, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > Y.Y.Y.Y: ICMP echo reply, id 360, seq 8, length 64
IP Y.Y.Y.Y > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 360, seq 9, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > Y.Y.Y.Y: ICMP echo reply, id 360, seq 9, length 64

18 packets captured
228 packets received by filter
92 packets dropped by kernel
```

Here "X.X.X.X" is my remote server's IP and "Y.Y.Y.Y" is my local network's public IP.
So, what I understand is that the ping packets are coming out of the Ubuntu box (10.1.1.12), 
 to the router (10.1.1.1), from there to the next router (192.168.1.1) and reaching the remote server (X.X.X.X). Then they come back all the way to the Debian router, but they never reach the Ubuntu box back.

What am I missing?

Here's the Debian router setup:

```
# ifconfig
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:0c:6d:82:0d:98  
          inet addr:10.1.1.1  Bcast:10.1.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::960c:6dff:fe82:d98/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:105761 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:48944 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:40298768 (38.4 MiB)  TX bytes:44831595 (42.7 MiB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x6000 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:f0:49:a4:47:38  
          inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6ef0:49ff:fea4:4738/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:38335992 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:37097705 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4260680226 (3.9 GiB)  TX bytes:3759806551 (3.5 GiB)
          Interrupt:27 

eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:0c:6d:82:c8:72  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:3408 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3408 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:358445 (350.0 KiB)  TX bytes:358445 (350.0 KiB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2767779 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1569477 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:3609469393 (3.3 GiB)  TX bytes:96113978 (91.6 MiB)


# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
127.0.0.1       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 lo
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth2
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2

# arp -n 
# Note: Here I have changed all the different MACs except the ones corresponding to the Ubuntu box (on 10.1.1.12 and 192.168.1.12)
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.1.118            ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.72             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.94             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.102            ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
10.1.1.12                ether   00:1e:67:15:2b:f0   C                     eth1
192.168.1.86             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.2              ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.61             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.64             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.116            ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.91             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.52             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.93             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.87             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.92             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.100            ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.40             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.53             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.1              ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.83             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.89             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.12             ether   00:1e:67:15:2b:f1   C                     eth2
192.168.1.77             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.66             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.90             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.65             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.41             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.78             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2
192.168.1.123            ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth2


# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination   

# iptables -L -n -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.1.1.0/24         !10.1.1.0/24         
MASQUERADE  all  -- !10.1.1.0/24          10.1.1.0/24         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

And here's the Ubuntu box:

```
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:67:15:2b:f1  
          inet addr:192.168.1.12  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:67ff:fe15:2bf1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28785139 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19050735 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:32068182803 (32.0 GB)  TX bytes:6061333280 (6.0 GB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:b1a00000-b1a20000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:67:15:2b:f0  
          inet addr:10.1.1.12  Bcast:10.1.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:67ff:fe15:2bf0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:285086 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12719 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:30817249 (30.8 MB)  TX bytes:2153228 (2.1 MB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:b1900000-b1920000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:86048 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:86048 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11426538 (11.4 MB)  TX bytes:11426538 (11.4 MB)

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
10.8.0.0        192.168.1.10    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

# arp -n
# Note: Here I have changed all the different MACs except the ones corresponding to the Debian box (on 10.1.1.1 and 192.168.1.10)
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.1.70             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.90             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.97             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.103            ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.13             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.120                    (incomplete)                              eth0
192.168.1.111            ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.118            ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.51             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.102                    (incomplete)                              eth0
192.168.1.64             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.52             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.74                     (incomplete)                              eth0
192.168.1.94             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.121            ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.72             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.87             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.91             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.71             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.78             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.83             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.88                     (incomplete)                              eth0
192.168.1.82             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.98             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.100            ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.93             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.73             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.11             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.85                     (incomplete)                              eth0
192.168.1.112            ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.89             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.65             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.81             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
10.1.1.1                 ether   94:0c:6d:82:0d:98   C                     eth1
192.168.1.53             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.116            ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.61             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.10             ether   6c:f0:49:a4:47:38   C                     eth0
192.168.1.86                     (incomplete)                              eth0
192.168.1.119            ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.66             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.1              ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0
192.168.1.1              ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth1
192.168.1.92             ether   NN:NN:NN:NN:NN:NN   C                     eth0

# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination  

# iptables -L -n -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Edit:** Following Patrick's suggestion, I did a tcpdump con the Ubuntu box and I see this:

```
# tcpdump -i eth1 -qtln icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
IP 10.1.1.12 > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 21967, seq 1, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > 10.1.1.12: ICMP echo reply, id 21967, seq 1, length 64
IP 10.1.1.12 > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 21967, seq 2, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > 10.1.1.12: ICMP echo reply, id 21967, seq 2, length 64
IP 10.1.1.12 > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 21967, seq 3, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > 10.1.1.12: ICMP echo reply, id 21967, seq 3, length 64
IP 10.1.1.12 > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 21967, seq 4, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > 10.1.1.12: ICMP echo reply, id 21967, seq 4, length 64
IP 10.1.1.12 > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 21967, seq 5, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > 10.1.1.12: ICMP echo reply, id 21967, seq 5, length 64
IP 10.1.1.12 > X.X.X.X: ICMP echo request, id 21967, seq 6, length 64
IP X.X.X.X > 10.1.1.12: ICMP echo reply, id 21967, seq 6, length 64
^C
12 packets captured
12 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

**So the question is: if all packets seem to be coming and going, why does ping report 100% packet loss?**

Comment: what does your iptables config look like? Are you blocking ICMP packets?

Comment: No, I'm not. I've just added the output of `iptables -L -n` for the Debian router. It's empty.

Comment: I am, but doesn't these do that?: `MASQUERADE  all  --  10.1.1.0/24         !10.1.1.0/24` `MASQUERADE  all  -- !10.1.1.0/24          10.1.1.0/24`

Comment: What about a tcpdump from the 'ubuntu box'? The tcpdump from 'debian router' clearly shows the reply packets being sent. Tcpdump operates outside kernel level filtering, so if the kernel is dropping the replies for any reason, tcpdump on 'ubuntu box' should at least show them making it to the box. On another note, you've provided a lot of useful info in a very clear manner, nice to have here.

Comment: Thanks, @Patrick. I did a tcpdump on the Ubuntu box and the packets seem to be coming back, but ping still shows 100% packet loss.

Comment: @ElBarto I have a sneaking suspicion what it is. Run `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth1/rp_filter` and see if pings work then.

Comment: Nope, nothing changes. Ping doesn't work but tcpdump still shows packets coming and going.

Comment: Can you please add your arp and routing tables for both the ubuntu and debian boxes?  I notice that your address ranges overlap on both servers, your NATted range of `192.168.1.0/24` on `eth2` of the debian box is the same as the physical range on `eth0` of the ubuntu box, I'm setting up some VMs to test my theory but I think the routing may be getting jacked if those two interfaces are on the same logical network.

Comment: Indeed, both the Debian and Ubuntu boxes are on the 192.168.1.0/24 network as well (this is while I'm setting things up and doing tests). I was afraid that could interfere, but I thought that since I was excplicitly telling `ping` to use `eth1` there shouldn't be any problems.The routing tables are already on my post. I'll add the ARP tables.

Comment: I noticed the routing tables after I posted (OS X has a way of hiding some visual cues from you ;). I have a sneaky suspicion that if you do a tcpdump on `eth0` of the ubuntu box for icmp you will see reply packets.  Can you down `eth0` on the ubuntu box and clear the arp cache of the debian box and try your ping again?

Comment: I was about to test the `tcpdump` on `eth0`, when I realized something changed since the last time I posted the output of the `tcpdump`s.  I'm not sure why, because everything seems to be the same. But now when I ping I see ICMP requests leaving the Ubuntu box but no reply coming back. On the remote server I see requests and replies. But on the Debian router I don't see anything... on none of the interfaces! My guess is that now, the Ubuntu box is talking directly to the router on 192.168.1.1 THOUGH sending requests with IP 10.1.1.12, so it can't route back. But why??

Comment: @El-Barto, Could you please ping from Ubuntu:eth1 and simultaneously capture on Debian:eth2 to demonstrate what is happening with NAT after you force the Ubuntu to send all traffic through the Debian again?

Comment: You see the replies on the Ubuntu box - so to my understanding you can sort out all other hosts as the source of the problem. You only showed the iptables config of the debian box - how is iptables configured on the Ubuntu box?

Comment: @tim, if you look at the very bottom of his Ubuntu capture, you'll see the output of `iptables -L -n`... is that what you're looking for?

Comment: The iptables of the Ubuntu box is also there, please check again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your question in the comments:

> On the remote server I see requests and replies. But on the Debian router I don't see anything... on none of the interfaces! My guess is that now, the Ubuntu box is talking directly to the router on 192.168.1.1 THOUGH sending requests with IP 10.1.1.12, so it can't route back. But why??

From the Ubuntu server:

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0 <---
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
```

At the time you captured this routing table, you have a lower metric default through `eth0` pointing to your router at 192.168.1.1 (i.e. not the debian machine).  A lower metric default is always followed first, which means Ubuntu wants to send all non-connected traffic directly to 192.168.1.1.

When you have downtime available, please remove that default with

```
route del default gw 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
```

I'm still simmering on the bigger problem (original sniffer traces show ping replies on Ubuntu:eth1, but no pings accepted by the OS).  Could you please ping from Ubuntu:eth1 and simultaneously capture on Debian:eth2 to demonstrate what is happening with NAT after you force the Ubuntu to send all traffic through the Debian again?

Comment: Thanks, your answer about the metric was helpful. Right now I can't remove the default route through 192.168.1.1, but I'll check that later. Currently the tcpdump on Debian:eth2 doesn't show anything, (I think) because packets are being sent directly to 192.168.1.1. But what happened before is on my original post. Check where it says "From the Debian Router I see this".

Comment: It's hard to say about the original problem... my suggestion: rebaseline everything after you remove the default... do all your sniffer captures at once.  Also, if possible get src / dest mac-address information in addition to src / dest IPs... the perfect world is to use `tshark` (wireshark in text mode), and you can specify which fields you want to capture... see [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379794/python-subprocess-adds-extra-quotes-to-my-shell-arguments) for an example. Finally, can you ping other destinations on the internet when the problem is happening?

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I'll check without the default route in a couple of hours when people leave the office. Regarding other destinations, it's funny. I've just tried to ping google.com and I'm getting the same result as I had previously pinging my remote server: I can see ICMP packets coming and going through the appropriate interfaces but `ping` still shows 100% packet loss. I'm guessing this difference between Google and my remote server has to do with routes cache. Am I right?

Comment: I can't say about the reason for ping failures yet... I don't have enough evidence.  This is an unusual problem... a few suggestions to help diagnose.  Use `ping -v <destination>` to see if you get more diagnostics for why pings are failing... Also please walk your pings, starting with localhost, then the ubuntu ethernet ip addr, then the default gw, one hop after, and so on until you find where they start failing.  Also, please do not specify the interface when you do so...

Comment: I'll check in a couple of hours. Currently if I ping without specifying an interface, it will route through the default gateway which is 192.168.1.1.

Comment: @El-Barto, even walking your pings now with `ping -v <destination>` now may give you useful information because pings to google.com are failing while you are defaulting through 192.168.1.1.  BTW, what is 192.168.1.1, and can you show the routing / arp table on it?

Comment: No, if I ping google.com without specifying the interfae, it uses `eth0`, routes through 192.168.1.1 and works fine. The problem is trying to ping google through the Debian box which is the router for the 10.1.1.0/24 network. 192.168.1.1 is a small Cisco router. I don't have access to it from here. Both the Debian and the Ubuntu box are connected to that router. What I'm trying to do is make the Debian box work as a router behind the Cisco router (in the future it will replace it).

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this exactly with virtual machines, and I can verify that the problem is definitely the route.  Adjusting the metric of the `192.168.1.1` route higher than the `10.1.1.1` route will fix the problem and route all of the traffic through the debian box.  What I don't fully understand is that I don't see any of the return packets hit any of the iptables chains on the ubuntu box.  The only chain that's seeing packets on that interface is `OUTPUT` (non-nat).

Comment: Well, I removed the default route through 192.168.1.1 and now *almost* everything works :) I can ping google.com and almost any other remote host from the Ubuntu box and it goes through the Debian router. The only one that doesn't work is the remote server I was using to test from the start. I'm not sure what can be the problem... maybe some sort of cache somewhere or something I messed up during my tests. I'll  appreciate if you have any other ideas, but since I can reach all other hosts, I'll consider the question answered. Thank you very much!  I'll award the bounty as soon as I'm allowed.

Comment: i am on my cell, so my capabilities are limited, but what does the verbose ping say is happening when the pings fail to your remote server?

Comment: Nothing, actually. It doesn't print any other different information.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. For the moment I think I have enough to move forward. But I'll keep your contact at hand just in case.

Answer (score 8):

Did you check if [reverse path filtering](http://www.tolaris.com/2009/07/13/disabling-reverse-path-filtering-in-complex-networks/) is enabled on the Ubuntu box?

It's a sysctl setting (`net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter`), it will filter incoming packets if the source address is coming in on the "wrong" interface ( i.e. not the interface that the kernel would route it to )

You could also try `net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians=1` to try to see what's happening.

Comment: This comment got me in the right direction, but I had to disable it for the specific interface, like: `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter=0`

Answer (score 2):

The key to make this work is to create separate routing tables for the different interfaces, and tell the networking stack to use these routing tables instead of the default one.

In your case this should make `ping -I eth2 8.8.8.8` work:

```
# register the 'foo' table name and give it id 1
echo '1 foo' >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

# setup routing table 'foo'
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth2 src 192.168.1.10 table foo
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 table foo

# use routing table 'foo' for address 192.168.1.10
ip rule add from 192.168.1.10 table foo
```

More information on routing for multiple uplinks can be found in the LARTC HOWTO:
http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

Answer (score -1):

If your iptables is completely blank (apart from the masquerade statement) then you likely need to add a FORWARDING chain to permit traffic through the box.  Try starting from a known working config-

http://wiki.debian.org/DebianFirewall#Using_iptables_for_IPv4_traffic

This also includes confirmation that you're set to forward in sysctl and such.

Comment: FORWARD chain has its policy set to ACCEPT, its fine. The tcpdump also shows the packets being properly forwarded (both directions).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but your default route from the Ubuntu box is via a separate router, not the Debian box.  On the Ubuntu box you specify you want the packets to source from 10.1.1.12 but your default route is via 192.168.1.1.  If you want the Debian router to be translating this traffic then the Ubuntu host needs to route its outbound traffic via that device, not the router.  Try adding a route to your remote server via the Debian box and see how that works.

Comment: The thing is that the Debian box is currently behind another router. So the path the packets should follow is from the Ubuntu box, to the Debian box, through the other router to the remote server on the Internet (and back). From what I see on tcpdump this seems to be working, but at some point there's something missing because `ping` reports the packets as lost.

Answer (score -1):

> You need to configure NAT.

In a typical configuration, a local network uses one of the designated "private" IP address subnets. A router on that network has a private address in that address space. The router is also connected to the Internet with a "public" address assigned by an Internet service provider. As traffic passes from the local network to the Internet, the source address in each packet is translated on the fly from a private address to the public address. The router tracks basic data about each active connection (particularly the destination address and port). When a reply returns to the router, it uses the connection tracking data it stored during the outbound phase to determine the private address on the internal network to which to forward the reply.

Comment: NAT is already configured. Notice that the packets in both the tcpdump on the router, and the tcpdump on the remote server both show the packets having been SNATed to the new address. The tcpdumps also show the return packets being properly restored.